# Copy&pasting the root partition, fstab is ignored

Tags: boot, 16.04, partitioning, fstab

I want to resize my root partition. From what I gather, the only way to do this is by deleting the partition and re-creating it with the larger size.

So I deleted an old Windows partition (sda1) and copy-pasted my current Ubuntu partition (sda6), and created a new UUID for it. I then marked sda1 as `boot` and changed `/etc/fstab` defining it as root, and changed sda6 from / to a custom mount point in `/media/`. These operations should be equivalent to resizing sda6. This is fstab currently:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sda1 : (new partition copied with gparted)
UUID=e407bc1c-4c2d-4dae-80ce-e6bd96346698   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=18abc384-a610-4f65-8430-0109548a89ef   /media/lbrito/ubuntu-old ext4 defaults
# ... swap etc
```

However, much to my surprise, fstab seems to be ignored after restart, and sda6 (the old, small partition) keeps getting defined as root:

[image]

`/etc/mtab`:

```
# ...
/dev/sda6 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda6 /media/lbrito/ubuntu-old ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda6 /var/lib/docker/aufs ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
```

So why is `sda6` ignoring fstab and being defined as root?

Comment: Your gparted shows sda1 mounted at /.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, that's the core of my question. Why is it still on `/` if I changed it to `/media/lbrito/ubuntu-old` in fstab?

Comment: Isn't sda1 your new root partition? So it should be mounted at /. And it is.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah, sorry, I meant sda6. As can be seen in mtab and gparted, sda6 is (wrongly) mounted on /, which I think is the core issue here.

Comment: sda1 is supposed to be the new root partition and is correctly mounted to /.

Comment: OK, so you have 2 partitions mounted on /?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56184/discussion-between-brito-and-organic-marble).

Comment: I've actually managed to simulate this situation in a virtual machine.  I don't think you are really booting off of sda1.  Notice it isn't really mounted (no key icon in gparted).  Investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From investigations in a virtual machine where I believe I managed to reproduce your case, you are only a few steps away from achieving your goal.  This fix assumes your machine boots to a state equivalent to that shown in your `gparted` picture above: you have booted from `sda6` and `sda1` is not mounted but shows a mount point of `/` and the boot flag. It also assumes that an `fstab` exists on `sda1` that shows `sda1` mounted at `/`.

From this point:

1. In `gparted`, select the `sda1` partition and from the right-click
   menu, select "Mount at /"
2. Exit gparted, open a terminal, and type `sudo update-grub`.
3. Reboot your computer.

This should get you to your desired end state of booting off `sda1` and having `sda6` mounted at a different point than `/`.

Comment: Bingo! This worked flawlessly.
I am still at a loss as to why fstab was ignored by Ubuntu though.

Comment: I have to admit I don't fully understand it either.